# Assign txt file data to struct node in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, fstream, assign

Ok so I have never worked with fstream before or opened and read and files in a program. My instructor just gave a few lines of code that open, read, and close a text file. I'm supposed to take the data out of the text file and put it into separate nodes in a linked list and then go on to do other things with it which is not important because I know how to do it. My problem is that I don't know how to a assign these values to the struct values.

The txt file looks like this:

Clark Kent    55000       2500     0.07

Lois Lane     56000       1500     0.06

Tony Stark    34000       2000     0.05

…

I have created a structure called Employee and then basic insert functions so I can add new nodes to the list. Now how do I get these names and numbers into my structure.

here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    string firstN;
    string lastN;
    float salary;
    float bonus;
    float deduction;

    Employee *link;
};

typedef Employee* EmployPtr;
void insertAtHead( EmployPtr&, string, string, float, float,float );
void insert( EmployPtr&, string, string, float, float,float );

int main()
{
    // Open file
    fstream in( "payroll.txt", ios::in );

    // Read and prints lines
    string first, last;
    float salary, bonus, deduction;

    while( in >> first >> last >> salary >> bonus >> deduction)
    {
        cout << "First, last, salary, bonus, ded: " << first << ", " << last << ", " << salary << ", " << bonus << ", " << deduction <<endl;
    }

    // Close file
    in.close();

    EmployPtr head = new Employee;


 }

void insertAtHead(EmployPtr& head, string firstValue, string lastValue,
            float salaryValue, float bonusValue,float deductionValue)
{
    EmployPtr tempPtr= new Employee;

    tempPtr->firstN = firstValue;
    tempPtr->lastN = lastValue;
    tempPtr->salary = salaryValue;
    tempPtr->bonus = bonusValue;
    tempPtr->deduction = deductionValue;

    tempPtr->link = head;
    head = tempPtr;
}

void insert(EmployPtr& afterNode, string firstValue, string lastValue,
        float salaryValue, float bonusValue,float deductionValue)
{
    EmployPtr tempPtr= new Employee;


    tempPtr->firstN = firstValue;
    tempPtr->lastN = lastValue;
    tempPtr->salary = salaryValue;
    tempPtr->bonus = bonusValue;
    tempPtr->deduction = deductionValue;

    tempPtr->link = afterNode->link;
    afterNode->link = tempPtr;
}
```

Also, I have tried searching this and results have came up but they all opened and read the data differently than what i was given. I am new to c++ coming from java so I do not understand some of the code that I see sometimes.

Comment: Did your instructor not cover how to instantiate objects?

Comment: Yes I know how to instantiate an object haha, i basically just don't know whats going on in the while loop. The data gets formatted and printed but i'm not sure how that's happening, I don't really see any code that assigns the text data to these variables first, last, salary etc.. in order to be printed how it is. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EmployPtr head = new Employee;

while( in >> first >> last >> salary >> bonus >> deduction)
{
    cout << "First, last, salary, bonus, ded: " << first << ", " << last << ", " << salary << ", " << bonus << ", " << deduction <<endl;
    insertAtHead (head, first, last, salary, bonus, deduction);
}
```

You already had 99% of the solution.  You just have to construct the list as you read the file.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I just didn't know that the values had already been assigned to something.